# Inserting into a sorted doubly linked list c++

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

trying to fix my doubly linked list code to sort on insertion, any ideas. Here is what I have. It inserts into the list, just unsorted. Been struggling with this for a little while now. Much appreciated.

```
template <typename T>
bool DoublyLinkedList<T>::insert(T data)
{
    int i = 0;
    Node<T> *tmp, *newNode;
    bool check = false;
    newNode = new Node<T>(data);
    tmp = mHead;

    if (newNode == NULL)
        return false;

    if (mHead == NULL)
    {
        mHead = newNode;
        mTail = newNode;
        mCount++;
        return true;
    }

    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        if (tmp->mNext == NULL)
        {
            if (tmp->mData <= data)
            {
                newNode->mPrevious = tmp;
                tmp->mNext = newNode;
                mTail = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                newNode->mNext = tmp;
                tmp->mPrevious = newNode;
                mHead = newNode;
            }
        }
        else if (tmp->mNext->mData >= data)
        {
            newNode->mPrevious = tmp;
            newNode->mNext = tmp->mNext;
            tmp->mNext->mPrevious = newNode;
            tmp->mNext = newNode;
            break;
        }

        tmp = tmp->mNext;
    }

    mCount++;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The theory is simple: Find the first node with a bigger (or smaller, depending on sort order) value than the one you want to insert. And add the new node before the found node. In practice it might be a little harder, which is why you might want to to it on paper first before writing the code. Remember the corner-cases when the new value should be inserted before the head or after the tail of the current list.

Comment: As for your problem, if you don't want to start over with the function (using my advice from above) then you need to learn how to use a debugger, and how to step through your code line by line, as that will help you find problems like you have.

Comment: To aid in debugging, in what cases is it not inserted properly? At the beginning? at the end? any case in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the error is with your else if.  Your current implementation compares "data" to the value in the node AFTER "tmp" and, by design, does not allow anything to be prepended to the list.

In the event that you have a list [4, 7] and you input a node with value 3, you are completely ignoring the first element and comparing with the second - resulting in [4,3,7].  Consider comparing data to tmp->mData rather than tmp->next->mData and adjust the logic accordingly.

In addition, when using a generic data type (), you shouldn't be relying on a simple "greater than" or "less than" comparison.  It's trivial to say that 6 < 7, but when comparing user defined structures or enumerated types, there may not be a clear order.